# Replace Firestore module `doc` with `document`?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I like the Firebase version 9 modules but I don't like `doc`. It should be `document`. This would match `collection`, which isn't `col`.

This code doesn't run:

```js
import { doc, collection, deleteDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

this.querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  deleteDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'users', doc.id));
});
```

I have to change it to

```js
import { doc, collection, deleteDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

this.querySnapshot.forEach((docElement) => {
  deleteDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'users', docElement.id));
});
```

I'd rather change it to

```js
import { document, collection, deleteDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

this.querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  deleteDocument(document(this.firestore, 'users', doc.id));
});
```

I have two questions. First, how do I make this request to the Firebase team? Second, can I make an alias for the `doc` module? I tried this but it didn't work.

```js
import { doc, collection, deleteDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class AppComponent {

  document: Function = doc;

  this.querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    deleteDoc(document(this.firestore, 'users', doc.id));
  });
}
```

That didn't work. :-)

Comment: You can file a request on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) (and also the underlying api [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk)), but I am 100% certain they would not make this change since it would be a breaking change for everyone who has been consuming this API for the past 5 years.  There would be very little advantage to breaking the API since it's very easy to customize the imports or make a wrapper API to your liking. It would also bring the API out of parity with other platforms that use doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) when importing:

```
import { doc as fireDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

this.querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // use fireDoc() here 
  deleteDoc(fireDoc(this.firestore, 'users', doc.id));
});
```

Comment: I'd avoid "document" as an alias though to avoid confusion with [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) API.

Comment: Works perfectly! That's what I wanted. I imagine that the Firebase team chose `doc` instead of `document` for the reason you said.